# python while loop with continue statement

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to print user name and pw using "while loop" and  only want to print the user status which is "on".

```
name_lst = ["koala", "cat", "fox", "hin"]
pw_lst = ["1111", "2222", "3333", "4444"]
status_lst = ["on", "off", "on", "off"]

i=0
while i < len(name_lst):
if status_lst[i] == "cat":
    continue
print("username: " + name_lst[i])
print("password: " + pw_lst[i])
i = i+1
```

The expect result should be:

```
username: koala
password: 1111
username: fox
password: 3333
```

However, I only got following result.

```
username: koala
password: 1111
```

Comment: `status_lst[i]` never equals cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the indentation is not good and it should be `status_lst[i] == "off"` not `"cat"` and you've created an infinite loop since when you continue you dont increment here is the correct code :

```
name_lst = ["koala", "cat", "fox", "hin"]
pw_lst = ["1111", "2222", "3333", "4444"]
status_lst = ["on", "off", "on", "off"]

i=0
while i < len(name_lst):
    
    if status_lst[i] == "off":
        i = i+1
        continue
    print("username: " + name_lst[i])
    print("password: " + pw_lst[i])
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Thanks!!
 It's work after adding a i = i+1 in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why use continue when you could just print data you want within the if statement?

```
name_lst = [
   ["koala", "1111", "on"], 
   ["cat", "2222", "off"], 
   ["fox", "3333", "on"], 
   ["hin", "4444" "off"] 
]

for data in name_lst:
    username, password, status = data
    if status == "on":
        print(f"username: {username}")
        print(f"password: {password}")
```